# Landsat 8 acquisition time and date

Tags: remote-sensing

[image]The the meta data text file that comes with Landsat scenes, contains an acquisition date and a scene center time in successive lines. I wanted to know if the image is recorded at the scene center time on the date of aquisition.

Comment: Can you provide said excerpt from the meta data?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the metadata file with the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to page 43 of the [Landsat Products Description Document](https://earth.esa.int/documents/10174/679851/LANDSAT_Products_Description_Document.pdf) the acquisition time is GMT when there is a "Z" behind the time.

[image]